# Trying to get property 'catid' of non-object using laravel

Tags: laravel

This is my code

```
public function edit($id) {
    $categories = Category::all();
    $category = Category::find($id);
    return view('categories.edit', compact('categories', 'category'));
```

}

Following is my edit form

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => ['categories', $category->catid], 'method' => 'put']) !!}
    <div class="form-group padding-t-20 {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
        {{ Form::text('name', $category->name, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Category']) }}
        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->has('name') ? $errors->first('name') : '' }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center padding-t-20">
            {{ Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd']) }}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**It works fine but when I use DB facade like below**

```
 public function edit($id) {
        $categories = DB::select('select * from tbl_menu_category');
        $category = DB::select('select * from tbl_menu_category where catid = ?', [$id]);
        return view('categories.edit', compact('categories', 'category'));
}
```

It gives me error Trying to get property 'catid' of non-object

Comment: As error message said check this part `catid = ?', [$id]`

Comment: $category = DB::table('tbl_menu_category')->where('catid',$id)->first();
try this one...

Comment: Yes worked @DejavuGuy

Comment: if did this help you I left answer in the bottom please mark if it is not difficult for you bro please ...

Answer (score 1):

execute the query

```
public function edit($id) {
        $categories = DB::table('tbl_menu_category')->get();  <--here
        $category = DB::table('tbl_menu_category')->where('catid', $id)->first(); <-- here
        return view('categories.edit', compact('categories', 'category'));
}
```

Comment: its giving error "Call to a member function get() on array"

Answer (score 1):

When you use DB::select() to query database it will return the results as array even if you are trying to get only record from database.

So the solutions is:

```
public function edit($id) {
  $categories = DB::select('select * from tbl_menu_category');
  $category = DB::select('select * from tbl_menu_category where catid = ?', [$id])[0]; <--- grab the first index of the array returned.
  return view('categories.edit', compact('categories', 'category'));
}
```

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 1):

`$category = DB::table('tbl_menu_category')->where('catid',$id)->first();` try this one...

if does this help you please rate me bro...

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know type of incoming data, `optional()` method is the best for these stuation..

```
optional($category)->catid
```

> Also don't forget to fetch result when you done with the query.. You
>   can use `first()` method for single result and `get()` for multiple
>   results

```
public function edit($id) {
        $categories = DB::select('select * from tbl_menu_category')->get();
        $category = DB::select('select * from tbl_menu_category where catid = ?', [$id])->first();
        return view('categories.edit', compact('categories', 'category'));
}
```

Also I have to say that, Eloquant is a advanced orm, so you don't have to write sql directly. You can use QueryBuilder methods, which make your queries more readable..

```
public function edit($id) {
        $categories = DB::table('tbl_menu_category')->get();
        $category = DB::table('tbl_menu_category')->where(catid,$id)->first();
        return view('categories.edit', compact('categories', 'category'));
}
```

Comment: using optional removes the error but does not get the data

Comment: @Peace I didin't see your query at the first and I update my answer then. You need the fetch your result when you done with the query, as above, you can use first() or get() methods